# Azure Traffic Manager - Disabled Endpoint still accessible?

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I have configured the Azure Traffic manager with two endpoints and could access the traffic manager. I thought of validating the scenario where endpoints are disabled, so I have disabled both the endpoints

[image]

to my surprise, still the traffic manager url is accessible for about ~2 mins. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected.

When you enable or disable the endpoint status, it controls the availability of the endpoint in the Traffic Manager profile. **The underlying service, which might still be healthy, is unaffected.** When an endpoint status is disabled, Traffic Manager does not check its health, and the endpoint is not included in a DNS response. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring#endpoint-and-profile-status

Also this note:

> Disabling an endpoint has nothing to do with its deployment state in
> Azure. A healthy endpoint remains up and able to receive traffic even
> when disabled in Traffic Manager. Additionally, disabling an endpoint
> in one profile does not affect its status in another profile.

Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-manage-endpoints

Comment: Thank you and understood. However how long it will take to exclude the disabled endpoint from the traffic manager?

Comment: You could find the TTL value. Clients continue to send traffic to the endpoint for the duration of Time-to-Live (TTL). You can change the TTL on the Configuration page of the Traffic Manager profile. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-manage-endpoints#to-disable-an-endpoint